# How to add two index.php file in .htaccess file for Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have two application inside WWW and I have created two index files id1.php and id2.php for two application app1 and app2

Structure

```
www\app1\application...
www\app2\application..
www\system\
```

location of id1.php and id2.php

```
www\app1\id1.php
www\app2\id2.php
```

I have created .htaccess as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(id1|id2\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app1/id1.php
```

With this I can open application app1, localhost\app1\welcome, but i can not open localhost\app2\welcome,

How can I add id2.php in .htaccess?

Comment: Does the file `app2\welcome` exists ? Or should `app1/*` be served by `app1/id1.php` and `app2/*` be served by `app2/id2.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `app1` and `app2` are supposed to be in your public URLs, and match the physical directories you have in your web root, don't put *any* app-specific rewrite rules for them in your root `.htaccess`. They should each have their own `.htaccess` in their directories. Ensure each has a correct base, e.g. `RewriteBase /app1/`. Make sure you don't interfere with URLs beginning with those directories by either doing no rewriting in the root, or explicitly ignoring them.

In `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# always match app dirs and do nothing, so allow their own rewriting
RewriteRule ^(?:app1|app2)(?:$|/) - [L]

# any non-app rules go here
```

In `/app1/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app1/
# files
RewriteCond $0 !^(?:index\.php|robots\.txt)$
# directories
RewriteCond $0 !^(?:resources|some-other-dir)(?:$|/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# do you really need to exclude dirs? are you allowing auto-index pages?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php [NS,L,DPI]
```